# DevExpress ASP.Net Component on Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, pinvoke, devexpress

I'm a happy user of DevExpress components, though currently I'm still on a linux web host.

In another thread I've spoken about my plans to move to a Windows environment so that I can use DevExpress's ASP.Net components. For some time now DevExpress's stand has been that their components is not likely to work on Mono, due to heavy usage of P/Invoke.

Having no prior experience with their ASP.Net components, my question is, has anyone successfully used their ASP.Net controls under Mono? I've read some posts that indicated that they had much better luck with ASP.Net stuff under mono than WinForms stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they state their controls are P/Invoke heavy, than you can either drop the controls or drop Linux. Mono is not at fault, only thing to blame is the code that has been written with only Windows in mind. And from my experience - code that breaks on Linux because of using P/Invokes will also break on Windows 64 bit (as the native libraries are not 32/64 bit agnostic like the managed assemblies).

Comment: agreed with what you say, apart from the use of DevExpress on x64 Windows.  I run 2008 & Win7 x64 with DevExpress components and they work fine.