# Errors Running DevExpress based ASP.NET Web Application In Ubuntu With Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, devexpress

When i run a devexpress and ASP.NET web application on ubuntu server, i find this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

All The other ASP.NET applications are running well on the same ubuntu server.

So, How can i run this application on the ubuntu server.

***The application already runs perfectly in the development environment on windows 7.***

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since other applications which not using DevExpress seems work well, here are possible explanations:

1) It may indicate DevExpress redistributable assemblies are not yet exist in your server. Ensure that all required assemblies exist in `/bin` folder of the application when deploying it to server. [The general information of redistributable assemblies](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4834) shows complete list of required assemblies to copy during deployment process.

2) Some DevExpress components use P/Invoke to communicate with WinAPI, which may trigger compatibility issues with Apache, Mono or even .NET Core environment. As *Ingvar* said [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q533525/devexpress-library-support-with-linux-mono), you can try installing Windows emulator such like **Wine**, but still cannot guarantee that all components will work properly.

Another available option is to drop all DevExpress helpers and using standard HTML helpers combined with various JavaScript libraries which has similar functionality.

Related issues:

[The "Could not load file or assembly 'X'" error message appears](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18620/the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-error-message-appears)

[ASP.NET MVC with DevExpress in Linux](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q582720/devexpress-asp-net-mvc-linux)

[DevExpress ASP.Net Component on Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377010/devexpress-asp-net-component-on-mono)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this - [DevExpress ASP.NET MVC - What is the difference between DevExtreme MVC Controls and classic ASP.NET MVC Extensions](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T516780/devexpress-asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-difference-between-devextreme-mvc-controls-and)

> Starting with v17.1, DevExpress officially introduced a new set of
>   components for the MVC platform: [Announcing the DevExtreme MVC
>   Controls for ASP.NET MVC and .NET Core - Available in v17.1](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2017/04/27/announcing-the-devextreme-mvc-controls-for-asp-net-mvc-and-net-core-available-in-v17-1.aspx).

You can either use the DevExtreme products or .NET core to port you application but right now DevExpress does not support Mono for ASP.NET controls.

The DevExtreme MVC Controls are based on the [DevExtreme client-side widgets](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Controls/Fundamentals/). They are more lightweight and their interaction with the server is used for obtaining data. They provide a more natural way of interacting with web services (OData, WebApi).